# How can I find a file in my git repository with SourceTree?

Tags: git, file, atlassian-sourcetree, history

How can I find a file in my git repository with SourceTree?

Currently, the file has to be present in some branch log, but I want to search on the repository.

I want to:

- right-click the file
- > > Log Selected...
- > > and peek at it's history.

The SourceTree file history is quite good.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In the working copy view there is a dropdown where you can select a filter for the visible files in the column below. Just select "All Files" instead of the "Pending" default.

On the right side there also is a Searchbox to filter this file list.

[image: SourceTree Working Copy View Screenshot]

Comment: This, for me, is just a workaround. I want to filter the general log view of my working copy, using the Search tab (next to File Status and Log/History tabs), and at the top right, in the existing Search dropdown, add the choice "Filename" alongside the existing "Commit Messages", "File Changes" and "Authors". You could even have an "All" choice. TortoiseGit or TortoiseSvn for example have this, and it's very convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You can view an individual file log by name, using the same method in juffel's answer (Workspace > File status > All files in combo), and then write the filename in the Search box at the right. You will see directly the file log without searching manually in the file list.